# jquery : adding nestable row and delete it through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a nestable list with a form on the top in order to add rows through ajax, without refreshing the page. The red cross is a delete button to remove each row.

Here is a visual :

[image]

And a part of the HTML/PHP nestable :

```
<div class="dd" id="users-levels">
    <ol class="dd-list">
        <?php
        $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM levels ORDER BY position ASC, creation_time DESC');
        $req->execute();
        while ($row = $req->fetch()) {
            ?>
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="<?=$row['level_id']?>" id="<?=$row['level_id']?>">
                <div class="dd-handle"><span class="pull-right"><a class="button-delete text-danger" id="<?=$row['level_id']?>"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></span><?=$row['name']?></div>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        $req->closeCursor();
        ?>
    </ol>
</div>
```

And the JQUERY part :

```
$('#form-parameters-users-levels-add').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#form-parameters-users-levels-add input[name="name"]').val();

    var buttonAdd = $('#form-parameters-users-levels-add .button-add');
    var buttonAddContent = buttonAdd.html();
    buttonAdd.attr('disabled', true);
    buttonAdd.html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    $.post(location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '/ajax/parameters.php?action=users_levels_create', $('#form-parameters-users-levels-add').serialize(), function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (obj['error']) {
            if (obj['message']) {
                alert(obj['message']);
            }
        } else {
            $('#form-parameters-users-levels-add')[0].reset();
            $('#users-levels ol.dd-list').prepend('<li class="dd-item" data-id="' + obj['level_id'] + '" id="' + obj['level_id'] + '"><div class="dd-handle"><span class="pull-right"><a class="button-delete text-danger" id="' + obj['level_id'] + '"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></span>' + obj['name'] + '</div></li>');
        }
        buttonAdd.removeAttr('disabled');
        buttonAdd.html(buttonAddContent);
    });
    return false;
});
```

I've although added a script to prevent default action when you click on the delete button because of the nestable functionnality, outside the *$(document).ready(function()* :

```
// mousedown prevent nestable click
$('.dd a').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

So, from here, if you want to delete existing strings, you click on the delete button then the row is removed. But if you enter a new string and add it to the database through Ajax then click on the delete button, the **mousedown prevent nestable click** function has no effect.

My JQUERY has no effect on new dynamic rows. Do you know why ?

Comment: elements have to exist when you bind events to them, otherwise can delegate events or bind again to new elements

Comment: Ok I see. Maybe it's easier to refresh the page after each add.

Comment: No, just use `on()` to delegate. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Use $(document).on('.dd a','mousedown', function(event)){ event.preventDefault(); return false;}); to create event on elements that are not created yet.